# Espelhamento Apache Tomcat - Work

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlet

Explicação : Atualmente quando vamos atualizar o projeto do nosso cliente ele fica "fora do ar" durante essa atualização, a ideia é conseguir atualizar o projeto sem precisar parar o cliente, vi algo relacionado a WORK do tomcat porém nada muito explicativo, alguns exemplos funcionais com JBOSS porém não vamos utilizar esse tipo de container, preciso de uma ajuda ou um caminho para fazer isso funcionar no Apache tomcat 8.5 ou superior.

Em algumas pesquisas vi que tinha configurações na qual o projeto tinha sua copia fiel no work e quando tivesse a alteração na principal ele apenas reescrevia a work porém tudo funcionava lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o que vc precise é do ***Parallel Deployment*** do Tomcat.

O princípio é basicamente fazer deploy de versões da sua aplicação, ex:

- sistema##001.war
- sistema##002.war

Feito isso, o seu usuário continuará acessando através da url padrão:

`http://seudominio.com:8180/sistema`

E o Tomcat fará o trabalho de direcioná-lo para a versão mais nova.

O pulo do gato é que os usuários que estiverem usando o sistema nem saberão o que houve até que acessem novamente o sistema.

Veja mais:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html

https://imasters.com.br/tecnologia/redes-e-servidores/conheca-o-zero-downtime-deploy-com-tomcat/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Gostei da ideia, tem como funcionar sem o .war ? pasta da aplicação direta.

Comment: O .war é o pacote gerado para o deploy. Mas vc pode fazer o deploy manualmente obedecendo o padrão nomeprojeto##001 ou nomeprojeto##1.2.3.

Comment: Obrigado jovem, vou aplicar na aplicação.